# Show always placeholder using react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a ways to always show the placeholder component even if there are some items selected?
I would like to have the placeholder in the same position as it is normally, not on top on the select or above.

[image]

Comment: You will have to create a custom placeholder, because by definition, the placeholder is only visible when an input does not have a value.

Comment: I tried but the Placeholder component is not rendered when there are some items selected

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the placeholder [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-paper-0nyxu?file=/example.js)

```
// @flow

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import Select from "react-select";
import makeAnimated from "react-select/animated";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();

export default function AnimatedMulti() {
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.select.inputRef.style.minWidth = "100px";
    myRef.current.select.inputRef.placeholder = "Placeholder#1";
  }, []);

  return (
    <Select
      ref={myRef}
      placeholder=""
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      components={animatedComponents}
      defaultValue={[colourOptions[4], colourOptions[5]]}
      isMulti
      options={colourOptions}
    />
  );
}
```